# how to return to previous fragment activity

Tags: android, back, android-fragmentactivity

Three fragment activities: `MainFragmentActivity`, `Reports` and `ReportsType`.

Reports is calling `ReportsType`.

There is a back button in `ReportsType` to go back with the following code:

```
public void goBackReport(View v)
    {
       finish(); // why MainFragmentActivity.java is called after finish()?
    }
```

But its always returning to `MainFragmentActivity.java`. But it should be `Reports.java`.

**UPDATE:**

**Reports.java**

```
public void showReport(View v) {
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    Intent i5 = new Intent(this, ReportsType.class);
    i5.putExtra("name", tag);
    FragmentTransactiontransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
        startActivity(i5);

    }
```

**ReportsType.java**

```
public void goBackReport(View v)
    {
       getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); //nothing happens
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no concept of calling `finish()` on `Fragment`. Instead, you should keep stack of fragments when performing transactions. For example:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);   // ft is FragmentTransaction
```

So, when you press **back-key**, the current activity (which holds multiple fragments) will load previous fragment rather than finishing itself.

Comment: But I am calling finish() on a class that extends FragmentActivity. Also my previous class is also the same. No fragments here.

Comment: when you are switching fragments then you dont need to call finish on its activity; instead, use addToBackStack when switching fragments

Comment: So where should I place addToBackStack(null)? If I place it in Reports.java and then call `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` in `ReportsType.java`, nothing happens. See my update.

Comment: In my case adding fragments to backstack slows down the performance of app.What to do for that

Comment: are you sure **addToBackStack** slows it down? perhaps its something else that may cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,MainFragmentActivity.class)
startActivity(i);
finish();

Intent i=new Intent(this,Reports.class)
startActivity(i);
finish();

Intent i=new Intent(this,ReportsType.class)
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

When you call new Activity write finish() in last

Comment: It isn't that easy. I called startActivity() and then finish() but it is giving few seconds delay on a finish() call with blank screen which isn't seem to be good. Any other alternative?

Comment: then try MainFragmentActivity.this.finish() instead only finish() and same for all.