# Showing the previous activity on back button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back

I have two activities: `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`

`Activity A` contains **three linear layouts**. Clicking on each linear layout is calling a `showReport` method which is starting `ActivityB`.

On Back Button click in `ActivityB`, I am getting result in `ActivityA` in a function `onActivityResult` and trying to refresh the `ActivityA`.

But the problem is -

When I click on any linear layout, the `onActivityResult` is called and my `resultCode` becomes equal to `0`, so condition **true** and `Activity A` gets called again.

How to call `Activity A` or how to get condition `resultCode` to be `0` only if I press **back button**.

My code sample-

**Activity A:**

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 2;

public void showReport(View v) 
    {
            tag = v.getTag().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", tag);
        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == 0) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            startActivity(in);  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Activity A:**

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(in);
```

If you are in activityA then why are you starting the same Activity again?
Anyway, You can check for back button press using this ->

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
//means back button was pressed in ActivityB
 }
}
```

**EDIT**
Remove this line from `showReport`

```
 this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: But the value of `RESULT_CANCELED` is always `0`. Its a constant. So no matter if you write `if (resultCode == 0)` or `if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)`. The problem is: clicking on any linear layout is also giving `resultCode` as `0`.

Comment: No its not. If ActivityB was succesful then it will return Result_OK, if you pressed Back button then the result code will be Result_cancelled . http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: `RESULT_CANCELED` is a constant, but the `resultCode` that you receive will change.

Comment: So I am using `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);` where I explicitly defined my `REQUEST_CODE = 2`. Is that a problem that I am getting the `resultCode` to be `0` even if I click any linear layout?

Comment: I am just starting the `ActivityB` on click of linear layout which is in `ActivityA`. This onclick code of `ActivityA` I already posted. Then do you want back button code of `Activity B` ? But the problem is coming before back button press i.e. when I am still in `Activity A`.

Comment: I have already removed that following others post but still not working. Still getting result code as RESULT_CANCELED.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27943/discussion-between-user603125-and-saurabh-jain)

Answer (score 0):

Try with some Global variable in `ApplicationClass`(which will call first time when your application will install )

```
public  boolean  check =false;
```

- check for ture value of boolean `check` in  `onActivityResult` of  `ActivityA`(First time its `check` is `false` so  it wont go further  )
- when press back on `ActivityB` then set value `check=true`
- make `false` value to `check` when you call `ActivityB` again

so  your `activityA` will call only if its came  form `ActivityB`

Comment: Thanx this resolved half of my problem. Now I am able to see `ActivityB` on click of linear layout. But when I click back button in `ActivityB`, I do not get into the `onActivityResult` method of `ActivityA`. Note that my back button is the software button and not hardware and it only contains `finish()` call to finish the `ActivityB` so that it return to `ActivityA`.

Comment: @SaurabhJain simply write startActivityForResult() in your ActivityA's onResume()

Comment: And what parameter should I pass in it? If I do `startActivityForResult(null, REQUEST_CODE);`, its giving nullpointerexception.

Comment: @SaurabhJain you can pass current  intent of activityA instead of null , and i dont understand  what need to call ActicityA in onActivityResult which is in ctivityA itself .

Comment: This is because I am getting `MainFragmentActivity` when I press back button and not `ActivityA`. So I am using this alternate way. See my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897502/how-to-return-to-previous-fragment-activity